# Hall system of finite group

Tags: group-theory

A Hall system $\Sigma$ of a finite group $G$ satisifes:

(a) For each $\pi \subseteq \mathbb{P}$, $\Sigma$ contains exactly one Hall $\pi$-subgroup, $H_\pi$ say;

(b) If $H, K \in \Sigma$, then $HK = KH$.

**Definition:** Let $G$ be a finite group with $H\leq G$. A Hall system $\Sigma$ of $G$ is said to reduce into $H$ if $\Sigma \cap H :=\{K \cap H \,|\, K \in \Sigma \}$ is a Hall system of $H$.

> **Question**: Suppose that $\Sigma$ is a Hall system of $G$, $L\leq G$ and $N\unlhd G$.
>
> If $\Sigma N/N$ reduces into $LN/N$, then $\Sigma$ reduces into $LN$.

This appears as Remark 4.17 on page 226 of *Finite soluble groups* by Doerk and Hawkes.

Suppose that $\Sigma N/N$ reduces into $LN/N$. Let $H \in \Sigma \cap \text{Hall}_\pi(G)$. Denote $H_0 = H \cap LN \in \Sigma \cap LN$. Then $H_0N = HN \cap LN$. Hence $H_0N/N = (HN \cap LN)/N = HN/N \cap LN/N \in \Sigma N/N \cap LN/N$. Since $\Sigma N/N$ reduces into $LN/N$, we obtain that $H_0N/N \in \text{Hall}_\pi(LN/N)$. We know that $H\cap N \in \text{Hall}_\pi(N)$. Now
$$ [N: N\cap H_0] = [N : N\cap H \cap LN] = [N : N\cap H]\;\, \text{is a} \;\pi'\text{-number}, $$ and so $$[LN : H_0] = [LN: H_0N][H_0N : H0] = [LN : H_0N][N : N\cap H_0]\;\, \text{is a} \;\pi'\text{-number} .$$ Consequently, $H_0 \in \text{Hall}_\pi(LN)$. Condition (a) of the Hall system is satisfied

For condition (b), let $H_0$ and $H_1$ be in $\Sigma \cap LN$. Then $H_0 = H \cap LN$ and $H_1 = K \cap LN$ for some $H, K \in \Sigma$. I know that $HK=KH$ but I'm not sure how to show that $H_0H_1 = H_1H_0$ as the book makes no mention of this being satisfied.

Comment: For $H,K \in \Sigma$, you have $H \cap K, HK \in \Sigma$. You have verified (a), so $H \cap LN$, $K \cap LN$, $H \cap K \cap LN$ and $HK \cap LN$ are all Hall subgroups of $LN$. Now $(H \cap LN)(K \cap LN) \subseteq HK \cap LN$, and by calculating their orders you will find that they are the same, so $(H \cap LN)(K \cap LN) = HK \cap LN$, which is a Hall-subgroup, and (b) follows.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you. Just a quick question. In some texts, they define the reducibility of a Hall system $\Sigma$ of $G$ into a subgroup $L$, if $H_\pi \cap L \in$ Hall$_\pi(L)$ for all $H_\pi \in \Sigma$. From what I see, this is precisely condition (a). Is it sufficient to show this if want to prove that a particular Hall system reduces into subgroup?

Comment: Yes, my argument above shows that in order to check whether a Hall system reduces into a subgroup, you just need to check (a).

Comment: Sorry @DerekHolt,  For a general case, if $H_\pi, H_\tau \in \Sigma$, then $H_\pi \cap H_\tau = H_{\pi \cap \tau} \in \Sigma$ and $H_\pi H\tau = H_{\pi \cup \tau} \in \Sigma$. Suppose that all Hall subgroups of $G$ reduce into some subgroup $K$ of $G$. Then $H_\pi \cap K$, $H_\tau \cap K$, $H_{\pi \cap \tau} \cap K$ and $H_{\pi \cup \tau}  \cap K$ are Hall subgroups of $K$. I am having a problem finding a counting argument to show that the orders of $(H_\pi \cap K)(H_\tau \cap K)$ and $H_\pi H\tau \cap K = H_{\pi \cup \tau}  \cap K$ are the same.

Comment: It follows from $|(H_\pi \cap K)(H_\tau \cap K)| = |(H_\pi \cap K)||(H_\tau \cap K)| /|(H_\pi \cap H _\tau \cap K)| = |(H_\pi \cap K)||(H_\tau \cap K)| /|(H_{\pi \cap \tau} \cap K)| $.